# android register form crashed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, phpmyadmin

i have written a code in java in eclipse that can let me create a product on a local database .. in fact its working but when its done, the application crashed and if i go to my  database i can see the product created
can anyone help me in this ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPrice;
    EditText inputDesc;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php" ;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
        inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });

}

class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }



    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Succes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You tell us it's crashed, but you don't tell us what the crash is or show us the logcat.  How are we supposed to guess?

Comment: error stack trace would give a better about the crash. So can we have the logcat?

Comment: probably you are getting this Exception `CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy...` because u are trying to show Toast and accessing Ui elements inside doInBackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line

```
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Succes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to your onPostExecute() method.

Comment: but i have a question, when it shows me the success messg the application has closed ... how can i make it that when it shows me the messg the application goes to another page in my app project ?

Comment: Ask another question.  Comments aren't the place to extend Q&A.  Also, dialogs are evil.  :)